# How to vertically align both image and text in a DIV using CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image and some text inside a div and I'd like to put the image and the text in the vertical center of the div using CSS. The problem is that I don't know how many lines of text I will have but the text and the image must be ALWAYS in the middle. For example, when there's only one line of text the div should look like this:

```
####################################
#  _______                         #
# |       |                        #
# |       |                        #
# | IMAGE |    text text text      #
# |       |                        #
# |_______|                        #
#                                  #
####################################
```

If eventually I have more lines or the height of text is larger than the height of the image then the image should be aligned, just like this:

```
####################################
#                                  #
#              text text text      #
#  _______     text text text      #
# |       |    text text text      #
# |       |    text text text      #
# | IMAGE |    text text text      #
# |       |    text text text      #
# |_______|    text text text      #
#              text text text      #
#              text text text      #
#                                  #
####################################
```

I'm in trouble to get this effect, is there any way without using javascript to do this?

Obs. The parent div of the div I'm referring to have position:relative so there's another problem.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Give both the image and the text a vertical-align: middle - the text needs to be contained in an element that is also display: inline. So markup like this:

```
<div>
  <span><img src="blah.jpg" /></span>
  <span>text text text</span>
</div>

div {
  display: table;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

should work. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq9G8/8/) to demonstrate (edited fiddle to show everything is vertically aligned within a container as well.)

EDIT: to get the behavior you want, I recommend using additional display properties - table for the container and table-cell for the contained elements. Fiddle link has been updated with the changes.

EDIT: the only way I could think of to get it to work was to wrap the image in another inline container, in this case a span. I've updated the fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: Yes, span is preferable so you don't have to add any display properties to the text container.

Comment: I tried in my code and in the fiddle, it works with one line of text but not with multi-line text.

Comment: Ah, ok, I'll update the fiddle with some modifications to achieve what I think you want.

Comment: It's almost the same effect, when the text is higher than the image the image isn't in the middle of text.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to tinker a bit more to handle that case.

Comment: @RedCurley updated fiddle again, but I had to modify the markup to get it to work. http://jsfiddle.net/kq9G8/8/

Comment: I was searching all over internet for this question for 2 years. Thanks @kinakuta

Answer (score 4):

You may try this, [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/DWThr/2/).

### CSS:

```
div.parent{ 
    border:solid black 1px;
    display:table;
    padding:5px; 
    width:100%;
    margin:5px 0; /* you can change/remove margin */
}
div.text{ 
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:justify;
}
div.parent .img{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
    padding-right:5px;
    width:50px; /* you can change width */
}
div.img img{ 
    width:100%;
    height:50px; /* you can change height */
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

​

### ​HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="img"><img src="http://example.com.img1.png" /></div>
    <div class="text">Some Text Some.</div>
</div>
```