# Align Text with Image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to line up text and an image below a title acting as a header, but the image keeps throwing off the divider between entries and messing up the page's alignment. Here's what it looks like (Django templates in use here)

Here's the code:

```
<script src="/static/js/downloadEntry.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% for entry in entries %}
  <div class="entry">
      <label class="titleText">{{ entry.title }}</label>
      <div class="contentContainer">
        {% if entry.image %}
            <img class="image" src="{{ entry.image.url }}">
        {% endif %}
        <p class="contentText">{{ entry.content }}</p>
      </div>
      <script>styleTitle("{{ entry.title }}");</script>
  </div>
  <hr class="entryDivider">
{% endfor %}
```

The relevant CSS:

```
.entryDivider {
    margin-top: 10px;
    size: 1px;
    width: 66%;
}
.entry {
    width: 66%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

 .titleText {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #666666;
    text-align: left;
    font-style: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
 }

.contentContainer {
    width:100%;
    display: block;
}

.contentText {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 200;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

I've tried a couple of different techniques to no avail. Ideally it looks something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/cSazm/5/, but within the div container. Something like:

```
[Title]
[Image, if one exists] [Content]
[Divider]
```

Here's a screenshot of how this is rendered:

[image: screenshot]

Any suggestions? I don't have much experience with frontend work (which is probably apparent)

Comment: [This may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408394/how-to-vertically-align-both-image-and-text-in-a-div-using-css/13408897#13408897).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking to do? [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/cSazm/26/)

```
div{
    display: block; 
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:10px 10px 0;
}    

h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
img{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align:top;
}    

p{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;    
}    

div hr {
    clear: both;
    border: none;
    padding-top: 5px; 
    margin:0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your containing `div` (in this case `.entry`), you can `clear` it:

```
.entry {
    width: 66%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    clear: both;
}
```

However, I recommend using something known as a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix):

```
.entry::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

This way, anything after the `.entry` will be cleared automatically.

As a side note, I recommend removing the `hr` elements and using `border-bottom` on the `.entry`.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsw4/).

Comment: This also worked well. Thank you for the advice on the divider as well

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
.content {
width: 100%;
}

.image {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.entryDivider {
    margin-top: 10px;
    size: 1px;
    width: 66%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XZ2Ax/

Just put everything in a div above the divider.

Answer (score 0):

after floated elements you should have a clearing element so that the floats dont "mix"

CSS

```
.clearfix {
   clear:both;
   height:0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/80/80/"  />

    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    </p>

</div>    
<br class="clearfix" />
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/80/80/"  />

    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
    </p>

</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cSazm/24/)