# Aligining a div to the right of another div in box(div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to align two divs next to each other in a box. I am using angularJS to generate the input boxes dynamically, i want to add an image for delete option beside each input box. I have used "display : inline-block". but it dosen't work.

The code that i have till now is :

```
<div class="contentBox box effectmission" ng-repeat="mission in missions">
        <div class="boxheader">
          <span style="font-size: large; font-family: monospace; font-weight: bold;">EDIT MISSION NAME</span><input id="{{mission.id}}" type="text" ng-model="mission.missionInfo" class="form-control" style="background-color: #e8e8e8">
        </div>
       <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
       <span style="font-size: large; font-family: monospace; font-weight: bold; margin-left:5%;">EDIT MISSION POINTS</span><br />
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <ol style="float: left; width: 100%;">
                <li id="missioncontent.id" ng-repeat="missioncontent in mission.missionContent" style="padding: 2px; width: 100%;">
                    <div>
                        <input id="{{missioncontent.id}}" type="text" ng-model="missioncontent.info" class="form-control" style="background-color: #e8e8e8; width: 80%;">
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: right; width: 20%; display: inline-block;">
                        <span>v</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
```

whatever i have got till now looks like this.

[image]

I want the input boxes and the image to align properly next to each other.(In place of 'v' i will be using an image.)

Comment: Set the sibling div to `float: left` too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically align both image and text in a DIV using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408394/how-to-vertically-align-both-image-and-text-in-a-div-using-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the `v` div before the `<input>` div in your HTML. You might need to `clear` it, too. (`display:inline-block` can be removed, since all floated elements are `display:block`.)

```
        <ol style="float: left; width: 100%;">
            <li id="missioncontent.id" ng-repeat="missioncontent in mission.missionContent" style="padding: 2px; width: 100%;">
                <div style="float:right; clear:right; width:20%;">
                    <span>v</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input id="{{missioncontent.id}}" type="text" ng-model="missioncontent.info" class="form-control" style="background-color: #e8e8e8; width: 80%;">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
```