# How to vertically align both image and text in a DIV.box using CSS (issue not similar to the already existing post)

Tags: html, css

I have created a 2x2 Layout DIV box with Float.

Now I want to put an image and a text inside the each DIV in the Vertical Center of the DIV using CSS. The number of lines in each DIV is Dynamic and I want the Image and Text to be in the Middle.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408394/how-to-vertically-align-both-image-and-text-in-a-div-using-css)

How can I achieve this with the existing design. I also want to have some space in between the DIV box vertically.

Also on top of this I want to insert an image (banner) which is wide (stretche and height is 100 px

Please help in achieving this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <p><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: verdana, sans-serif">Sample Text</span>
  </p>
  <p><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: verdana, sans-serif"></span>&#160;&#160;</p>

  <style type="text/css">
    DIV.box {
      BORDER-TOP: #e3f7fa 0px solid;
      HEIGHT: 150px;
      BORDER-RIGHT: #e3f7fa 0px solid;
      WIDTH: 40%;
      BORDER-BOTTOM: #e3f7fa 0px solid;
      FLOAT: right;
      CLEAR: none;
      BORDER-LEFT: #e3f7fa 0px solid;
      MARGIN: 0px 1% 1% 0px
    }
  </style>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #EBEBEB">
    <center>
      <h3 style="color: #0066CC">Service Governance</h3>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #EBEBEB">
    <center>
      <h3 style="color: #0066CC">Change Management</h3>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #EBEBEB">
    <center>
      <h3 style="color: #0066CC">People Board</h3>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #EBEBEB">
    <center>
      <h3 style="color: #0066CC">Software Asset Management</h3>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #EBEBEB">
    <center>
      <h3 style="color: #0066CC">Finance Management</h3>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #EBEBEB">
    <center>
      <h3 style="color: #0066CC">Vendor Governance</h3>
    </center>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: Also there are **thousands** of questions on Stack Overlfow about centering content. I suggest you try some research first.

Comment: Also, It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I made a Jsfiddle test for you.
Hope it helps.
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/denilsonjvv/8cs2qz25/3/)

```
   div.box {
  BORDER-TOP: #e3f7fa 0px solid;
  HEIGHT: 150px;
  BORDER-RIGHT: #e3f7fa 0px solid;
  WIDTH: 40%;
  BORDER-BOTTOM: #e3f7fa 0px solid;
  FLOAT: right;
  BORDER-LEFT: #e3f7fa 0px solid;
  MARGIN: 0px 1% 1% 0px;
}
.box h3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.wholeboxcontholder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wholeboxcontholder .imgsize{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.box img {
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-right: 40%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  align-content: center;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Graphic, but can we leave the Header in the box as it is and do the rest of the Coding.

I want the header to be as it is and the image and text should be vertically aligned under that.

Is that possible?

Comment: I added a new JsFiddle link, hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, I just figured out an issue with the edit, test this one for better output: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/denilsonjvv/8cs2qz25/4/)

Comment: Thanks mate, but I am looking for something like this to be incorporated in my JS. I am also fine if this can be achieved without using JS.

I am looking for something like this below my Heading Ex: service governance
http://jsfiddle.net/kq9G8/8/

Comment: @kumarma I think what you mean is a horizontal alignment, you can achieve this by getting the exact same code from the link you just gave me. Let me give you a jsfiddle demo in a little bit.

Comment: Graphicoding, am I doing something wrong here. As I cant see the same output in my page. I am using a <style type="text/css> for the CSS.
Also, there is a separate line created below the image and it is not aligned as per my requirement.

Can you please help me achieve this?

Comment: Contact me on skype @systemconnection or email denilsonjvv@gmail.com