# Align image and text properly in HTML

Tags: css, html

This is the example:
[image]

I want to align the *image* along side with the name but somehow the image just floats up a little higher. Any help?

**UPDATE:**

```css
#profile_name_header {
  background-color: #006400;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="profile_name_header">
  <img src=< ?php echo "./img/".$genderprofile. ""; ?> style = "height:30px; margin-bottom:0px;" >
  <?php echo $fullname;  ?>'s Profile
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please share your HTML and CSS code.

Comment: @chaitz9 - I already added it. Thanks!

Comment: Use vertical-align: middle css property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically align both image and text in a DIV using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408394/how-to-vertically-align-both-image-and-text-in-a-div-using-css)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `vertical-align` on the `img` since it's adjacent inline content.

```css
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-EK1g7sBpX74/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABU/AzsjRnL3mKk/photo.jpg?sz=32"> @Dranreb
```

A fancier way is to use flexbox, but it's overkill for your use case. If you wanted to do that, just give them a parent, and use `align-items` to affect vertical alignment.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-EK1g7sBpX74/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABU/AzsjRnL3mKk/photo.jpg?sz=32"> @Dranreb
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I've been searching for! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is a CSS Property called [vertical align](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp), which can be used to align several html elements in respecr to the text baseline. I'd suggest you set it to center, but try and see what fits best.

(Some further [reading](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/%20reading) about the conflicts among devs.)

Comment: Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

Assign one class name to the image. For e.g.

```
<img class="backgroundImg" src="images/bg.jpg" />
```

Then use these css properties:

```
.backgroundImg {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px; // or 10px
}
```

Based on your text leveling, just adjust the "top" value.

*Note:You can also use "id" and assign the same css properties.*

Comment: Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with proper **HTML** Markup......

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
figure{
width:620px;
display: block;
margin:0 auto;
}
figure img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
figcaption{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<figure>
<img src="https://unsplash.it/600/280" alt="">
  <figcaption>
    <small>Image Caption goes here</small>
  </figcaption>

</figure>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that!