# Center DOM created images inside a li

Tags: html, css

I created a little todo app in javascript that adds a new todo and deletes it:

```
function addTodo() {
    var item = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var text = document.createTextNode(item);
    var newItem = document.createElement('li');
    newItem.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(newItem);

    var removeTask = document.createElement('img');
    removeTask.setAttribute('src', '/images/trash.jpg');
    removeTask.setAttribute('id', 'trash');

    removeTask.addEventListener('click', function() {
        newItem.parentNode.removeChild(newItem);
    });
    newItem.appendChild(removeTask);
}
```

here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo list</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <form>
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter an activity..">
    <button type="button" onclick="addTodo()" class="add-button">+</button>
    </form>
</header>
  <ol id="todoList">
  </ol>
    <script src="./scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When a new item is created it adds the item and a trash can that removes the Todo, but as you can see from the photo the trash can img is a little bit higher than the text and I want them both to be aligned perfectly and not the trash icon to be higher. How can I do that with css? I tried to display them block, to set the margin-top and the position to relative, but still I can't make it right

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this helps:
[Align image and text properly in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500597/align-image-and-text-properly-in-html)

and apply it to Your `<img>` element

Comment: It did, simple and efficient